# Does the '\0' at the end of the string also get included here?

Tags: c++, string, strlen

If I declare a string with 10 elements like this:

```
char s[10];
```

then does the '\0'at the end occupy the 10th place or the 11th? Basically my question is that do we get 1 element less in the string?

And if I use the strlen() function to find this string's length, will the return value be inclusive of the null? I.e if the string is "boy", will the function give me 3 or 4?

Comment: the \0 can be inserted anywhere from index 0 to index 9 inclusive. It cannot appear in index 10  (The index range here is 0- 9).

Comment: As you are using C++ I will point out that you should be using the string class rather then arrays of `char` (or `char*` for that matter [fyi, not exactly the same]) Though I believe you are looking at embedded stuff, and that's like some alternate reality where nothing makes sense.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no 11th place, ie, yes, that is one less element to use.

Don't put a string longer than 9 chars in there.  `Strlen()` does not include the null terminator.

Eg:

```
char s[]="hello";
```

`s` is an array of 6 chars, but the `strlen()` of `s` is 5.

Comment: As this is tagged C++, I think that's a safe assumption :-)

Comment: I knew those had some kind of purpose ;)

Comment: An example of a language that does it differently is Modula2. There the terminating null is omitted if the number of characters is equal to the array count. All functions behave like C "-n" variants, one has to pass the upper bound of the buffer for every action, to allow the runtime to handle this case.

Comment: Upvoting this for fairness, because the OP doesn't seem to accept any answer anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the `\0` character will occupy the 10th place. Meaning, the string will only contains 9 input characters. And no, `strlen()` does not count the null character.

Answer (score 2):

If you declare an array like that, it doesn't need to have a zero byte at the end. If you call any functions that expect a string on it, it almost certainly will result in a crash. You need to initialize the array:

```
char s[] = "This is a test."
```

If you do something like this:

```
char s[10] = "012345678"
printf("%d\n", strlen(s));
```

It will obviously print 9. You can't put 10 characters in that array, since the null byte would get written out of the array bounds.

Answer (score 1):

If you declare an array of 10 characters, you must keep in mind that one of them has to be used for the string terminator, so you can store a maximum of 9 characters.

`strlen`, instead, returns only the number of "logical" characters, i.e. it won't count the null terminator.